# An $n$-hypercube is both $n$-vertex- and -edge-connected

Tags: graph-theory

I have come across some proofs for this, most of which take the $n$-disjoint paths approach. I came up with the following induction idea and I'd like to ask whether or not you find it sound.

The hypothesis holds for the 2-hypercube.

Suppose that the hypothesis holds for the ($n-1$)-hypercube. Then, we note that the $n$-hypercube is formed by two copies Q and Q' of the ($n-1$)-hypercube with a perfect matching between their vertices. Then, for Q (or Q') to be disconnected we have to remove $n-1$ vertices from it. So one vertex in Q is isolated and to disconnect the  $n$-hypercube we need to also remove its pair from Q'.

Comment: From wikipedia: 

"[The hypercube graph] is a n-vertex-connected graph, by Balinski's theorem" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph. 

I found this when trying to come up with a clean definition of "n-connected" ness. I wrote a paper on hypercube isometries once but it's been along time and I have long such forgotten such definitions. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: You want to prove that it is $n$-vertex connected? I don't think this proof is complete. First, it sounds like you're claiming that by deleting a minimum vertex cut from a graph $G$, you will have an isolated vertex, which is false (consider the [bowtie graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ButterflyGraph.html)). Second, you need to talk about all possible vertex cuts to show $n$-connectedness, but you only consider the ones that consist of a vertex cut of $Q(n-1)$ and some vertex in $Q'$. Showing $n$-connectedness requires you to show that every possible vertex cut must have size at least $n$.

Comment: @KevinLong I took the idea from http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/2term/ma006b/05%20connectivity%201.pdf. I don't really get the first bullet point at page 13 though. Do you? If so can you explain?

Comment: @Mason yes, this is the hypercube I am talking about. In my notes a hypercube is the cartesian product $Q_n = P_2 \times Q_{n-1}$. If you want me to elaborate on n-connected graphs, it's the minimum number of vertices that have to be removed for the graph to stop being connected.

Comment: You need the first bullet point to have a complete proof. Your proof shows that there is a vertex cut of size $n$, since $Q$ has a vertex cut of size $n-1$, and you can delete one more vertex to disconnect $Q_n$. But to prove that the graph is $n$ connected, you need to show that there is no smaller vertex cut. We already covered the case if the vertex cut disconnects $Q$ or $Q'$, now we assume that it doesn't, in which case it must remove all $2^{n-1}$ edges between $Q$ and $Q'$. This is because $Q$ has $2^{n-1}$ vertices and each vertex in $Q$ is in exactly one edge between $Q$ and $Q'$.

Comment: But there's another detail that's missing in that slide (they give the idea of the proof, and I imagine they wanted to leave the details to the reader), which is that the vertex cut will always induce an isolated vertex. This is by construction; in $Q_2$, we'll have an isolated vertex when we take a minimal vertex cut. Then by induction, if there is a minimal cut of $Q_{n-1}$ that induces an isolated vertex $v$, we delete that cut from a copy of $Q_{n-1}$ in $Q_n$. Then by deleting the neighbor of $v$ in $Q'$, the other copy of $Q_{n-1}$, we get a vertex cut of $Q_n$ that isolates $v$.

Comment: @KevinLong yes it's clear now, thank you very much!!

Comment: @KevinLong from what I understood is that we either prove that there will be an isolated vertex or, in the case where $Q$ is left disconnected, we can say that we have to remove at least one more vertex from the whole graph to disconnect it. So overall, the connectivity is at least $n$. But we can find a case where it is exactly $n$, and that is if we remove all the edges adjacent to a single vertex, that is, all its $n$ neighbors. That being said, the connectivity is $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above comments, I am posting my full proof, hoping it's correct.

The base is that $Q_2$ is 2-connected.

Then we observe that, $Q_n$ is an $n$-regular graph (easily proved by induction), so we can disconnect it if we remove the $n$ neighbors of a random vertex. So the connectivity $k$ is equal or less than $n$.

The induction hypothesis is that the hypercube $Q_{n-1}$ is $n-1$-connected, thus so are the hypercubes $Q$ and $Q'$ as defined above.

Let $S$ be a minimum separator of $Q_n$. We have two cases. 
*Case 1.* $S$ leaves both $Q$ and $Q'$ connected, so in order for $Q_n$ to disconnect, we have to remove ALL the edges connecting $Q$ and $Q'$, that is a vertex at one end of each edge. We know from the definition of hypercubes that both $Q$ and $Q'$ have $2^{n-1}$ vertices and thus, $S$ will have at least $2^{n-1}\ge n$ vertices. 
*Case 2.* If $S$ disconnects one of the small hypercubes, say $Q$ wlog, then it has at least $n-1$ vertices (because it is $n-1$-connected by the induction hypothesis) and we also have to remove at least one more vertex from $Q'$ to disconnect $Q_n$. So again, $S$ has at least $n$ vertices, which completes the proof because of our earlier observation.

**NOTE**: One can now easily prove that $Q_n$ is also $n$-edge-connected, since it is $n$-regular and the following holds every graph $G$:

$k(G) \le \lambda (G) \le \delta (G)$

where $k$ is the vertex-connectivity, $\lambda$ is the edge-connectivity and $\delta$ is the minimum degree of G.